I have an issue with asp drop down list i set postback is true when i change the item from dropdown then my language dropdown affected?
here the explanation
by default set complince and in language drop down is eng language
but when i change the item from drop down then language not getting correctly and set any other language why?
if i set post back is false then not affected ?
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpAuthType" runat="server" height="31px" CssClass="combobox" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpAuthType_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Rainbow Compliance Recorder" meta:resourcekey="drpAuthTypeli1Resource1" Value="RecordingRepository"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Active Directory" meta:resourcekey="drpAuthTypeli2Resource1" Value="AD"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Azure Active Directory" meta:resourcekey="AzureActiveDirectory" Value="Azure"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Rainbow" meta:resourcekey="Rainbow" Value="RB"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

code behind
  protected void drpAuthType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      try
      {
          if ((drpAuthType.SelectedValue == AuthenticationType.AD.ToString() || drpAuthType.SelectedValue == AuthenticationType.Azure.ToString() || drpAuthType.SelectedValue == AuthenticationType.RB.ToString()) && Convert.ToBoolean(Session["IsEmailTemplateEnabled"]))
          {
              hlForgotPassword.Visible = false;
          }
          else if (drpAuthType.SelectedValue == "RecordingRepository" && Convert.ToBoolean(Session["IsEmailTemplateEnabled"]))
          {
              hlForgotPassword.Visible = true;
          }

          txtPassword.Attributes.Add("value", txtPassword.Text);

          ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).SetFocus(drpAuthType);

      }
      catch (Exception)
      {

          throw;
      }
  }

